# What is particular meaning of the verb "pitch" here?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

What is particular meaning [of the verb "pitch" here](https://medium.com/message/my-failed-experiment-in-time-travel-3aa2240a6bc0#.6w6nhv6hy)? Are there any appropriate synonyms of it?

> In the process of writing this article I came across one email from 11
>   years ago. It turns out I pitched this exact piece— the one you are
>   reading right now — as a commentary to NPR, under the title “Mining My
>   Own Data”.

It has a very wide definition: [www.thefreedictionary.com/pitch](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pitch).

Comment: That'll be meaning 7: *Informal* To attempt to promote or sell, often in a high-pressure manner

Comment: @Hellion: Drat, beat me to to it!  But to be exact, it is the seventh definition under v.tr.

Comment: As for synonyms: advertise, sell, tout, hype, and so on.

Comment: He tried to sell the article to NPR, for them to produce as a commentary.

Answer (score 2):

From your dictionary.com link, this meaning is correct:
*35. (Marketing) slang: a persuasive sales talk, esp. one routinely repeated*

The term is used in sales, business, or marketing to describe when someone has an idea she is selling. Another person hearing the pitch may make the decision to buy or fund that idea. The term is used widely across industries.

For further clarification, there's an entire show where people pitch products and ideas: http://www.scienceofpeople.com/2014/01/pitch-idea-shark-tank/

Answer (score -1):

Pitch (Flip, Toss) Verb
throw or toss with a light motion

Example
flip me the beachball.

Pitch (Lurch, Shift) Verb
move abruptly

Example
The ship suddenly lurched to the left.

Pitch Verb
fall or plunge forward

Example
She pitched over the railing of the balcony.

Source http://hindi.wordinn.com/pitch

Comment: What does to **pitch** in the poster's example sentence mean? Your post doesn't answer the question, does it?

Comment: I provided (pitch verbs) to help asker

Comment: What if your post (any of your definitions) doesn't help the asker? Have you considered this? Please make sure you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.