# "a pitch to a company" What does this mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

This is also a TOEFL listening question.

An outside class student is taking a game creation class ( computer programming ) and in order for him to pass the class, he has to demonstrate his own project.

Here is the conversation between a professor and the student.

**Professor**

> Alright, that sounds like it would consititute an appropriate amount of work on your part. Now, the project also incorporates a presentation where the students demonstrate their prototype.

**Student**

> Yeah, I was figuring I'd present my project as if **it was a pitch to a company**. I figure it would be boring if I went through the whole design document in front of the class, so I'd create a slideshow and present it as if I was looking for investors or a publisher.

Could this mean, possibly, something like a submitting a resume to a company??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does mean by "start his pitch" means ?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/96073/what-does-mean-by-start-his-pitch-means) See also [What is particular meaning of the verb “pitch” here?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/82316/what-is-particular-meaning-of-the-verb-pitch-here) for the corresponding ***verb*** usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's common business jargon for a sales presentation.

[Pitch](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pitch) (MW) - Noun definition 8

> an often high-pressure sales presentation

---

Note: edited to replaced 'slang' with 'jargon'

Comment: Thanks a lot! Even a slang comes to this test? Whoa.....I mean shouldn't they be?

Comment: @KentaroT - What makes you think this is slang? The term "sales pitch" is well-recognized and often-used, especially in business. No slang here. That said, I wouldn't be surprised if the TOEFL would deliberately use words like _pin, pitch, set, light,_ or _rub_, that is, relatively simple words that happen to have a myriad of meanings. Being able to pick out which of several meanings is the applicable one is an important skill.

Comment: @J.R I just said since John is saying "It's common business slang..."..nothingelse.

Comment: @KentaroT - Oh, I see. I think _jargon_ might be a more apt word than _slang_ in this case, but even the word [_slang_](https://www.wordnik.com/words/slang) is elastic enough that it works in this answer.

Comment: @J.R. You're right - I should have used "jargon" instead of "slang".  I will edit.